# How to get dict without Url(...) on pydantic model.model_dump()?

Tags: pydantic

this is my code:

```
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    HttpUrl,
)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: HttpUrl


model = MyModel(url="https://io.com")
print(f"model_dump: {model.model_dump()}")
print(f'model_dump_json: "{model.model_dump_json()}"')
```

Result:

```
model_dump: {'url': Url('https://io.com/')}
model_dump_json: "{"url":"https://io.com/"}"
```

Model_dump_json() gives me a string.

How to get dict without Url(...) on pydantic model.model_dump()?

Thanks

I can use json.loads(model.model_dump_json()), but it is not normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `field_serializer`:

```
from typing import Any

from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    HttpUrl,
    field_serializer,
    FieldSerializationInfo
)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: HttpUrl

    @field_serializer("url")
    def ser_url(self, value: Any, info: FieldSerializationInfo):
        return str(value)


model = MyModel(url="https://io.com")
print(f"model_dump: {model.model_dump()}")
print(f'model_dump_json: "{model.model_dump_json()}"')
```

Output:

```
model_dump: {'url': 'https://io.com/'}
model_dump_json: "{"url":"https://io.com/"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case there is actually an even simpler answer. You can use the option `.model_dump(mode='json')`. See the following example:

```py
from pydantic import (
    BaseModel,
    HttpUrl,
)


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    url: HttpUrl


model = MyModel(url="https://io.com")
print(f"model_dump: {model.model_dump(mode='json')}")
```

Which prints:

```
model_dump: {'url': 'https://io.com/'}
```

I hope this helps!